# How to record information from sql table based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

record player information in the following table (player info).  check the maximum level of each player (player? ID) and the minimum gap under this level.

```
 player_id   level   gap
    -----------------------
    123         8       20
    123         9       40
    123         9       30
    246         [NULL]  10
    246         6       30
    246         6       20
    -----------------------
```

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: @ rows with highest level rank of player

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you would use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (player_id), t.*
from t
order by player_id, level desc, gap;
```

In either MySQL or Postgres, you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number(player_id) order by (level desc, gap) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's query, you can use `min()` and `max()` functions for this.

```
select min(t1.gap), t2.lev, t1.player_id
from tableA t1
inner join 
    (select max(lev) lev, player_id
    from tableA
    group by player_id) t2 on t2.lev=t1.lev and t1.player_id = t2.player_id
group by t1.player_id, t2.lev
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=jCfumz7PVB).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query in postgres:

```
select x.player_id, x.level, min(x2.gap) as gap 
from (select player_id, max(level) as level 
      from table group by player_id) x 
join table x2 using(player_id, level)
group by x.player_id, x.level;
```

the result will be like this:

```
 player_id   level   gap
    -----------------------
    123         9       30
    246         6       20
    -----------------------
```